# angular-bootstrap-md.es5.js not found problem

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

i install mdbootstrap in my angular project but when i compile my app this error appear on screen .

Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Angular project\Acontly\acontly\node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\esm5\angular-bootstrap-md.es5.js'

but exactly in such directory i have this file !

Comment: Did you tried to use our 5min-quickstart guide to install MDB Angular in your project? 
https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/5min-quickstart/

If yes, please provide me the reproduction steps with which I'll be able to reproduce your problem.

Also, please provide a code of app.module.ts (or another module in which you're importing MDB Angular), package.json and angular.json files.

Comment: thank you. i solved problem and it work very well now.